# change style of menuItem when clicked in IceFaces menuBar

Tags: css, jsf, icefaces

My page has a menuBar that has some menuItems. The menuItems are highlighted on mouseover, but I need to highlight it as soon it is clicked like in a tabView.

```
 <ace:menuBar id="menuBarHeader" autoSubmenuDisplay="true"
            styleClass="menue">
            <ace:menuItem id="menuItemStart" value="Start"
                icon="ui-icon ui-icon-home" url="/layouts/welcome.xhtml"
                styleClass="menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Highlight active menu based on URL:

Fragment of helper controller:

```
    public String getActiveMenu() {
        final String url = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestServletPath();
        String activeMenu = url.replaceAll("/screens/([^/]+)/.*", "$1");
        // exceptions (not standard urls)
        if (isHomeMenuActive(activeMenu)) {
            activeMenu = "home";
...
```

xhtml:

```
  <ace:menuItem id="menuItemStart" value="Start"
                icon="ui-icon ui-icon-home" url="/layouts/welcome.xhtml"
                styleClass="menu #{menuHighlightController.activeMenu eq 'home' ? 'menuActiveItem ' : ''}" />
```

Highlight menu with use anchor pseudo-classes:

```
.menuItem{
a:link{
  background-color:blue;
}
a:visited{
  background-color:purple;
}
a:hover{
  background--color:orange;
}
a:focus{
  background-color:green;
}
a:active{
  background-color:red;
}
}
```

Highlight with use Java Script:

xhtml:

```
 <ace:menuItem id="menuItemStart" value="Start" onclick="changeColor();"
                    icon="ui-icon ui-icon-home" url="/layouts/welcome.xhtml"
                    styleClass="menu" />
```

JS:

```
function changeColor(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active-menu")
}
```

Comment: I don't want to check the current URL, just want to set other color when it is clicked

Comment: each <a:menuItem> produce <a href> tag, for this tag you can use: a:link{
  color:blue;
}
a:visited{
  color:purple;
}
a:hover{
  color:orange;
}
a:focus{
  color:green;
}
a:active{
  color:red;
}